# After insert trigger to update a table with query results from another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

This question is related to a [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30092072/return-rows-with-the-highest-value-on-one-column-corresponding-to-a-given-value). I have 2 MySQL tables, **raw_contacts** and **distilled_contacts**. The table structures are as follows:

```
raw_contacts
--------------------------------------------
ID (primary auto-increment, int)
PHONE (composite unique with NAME, varchar)
NAME (composite unique with PHONE, varchar)
FREQUENCY (int)
Composite unique key is named PHONENUM

distilled_contacts
---------------------------------------------
ID (primary auto-increment, int)
PHONE (unique, varchar)
POPULARNAME (varchar)
```

Every time a new row is inserted into **raw_contacts**, I need a new entry to be made in **distilled_contacts** for the phone number in context with the name with highest frequency updated in the **POPULARNAME** field. If an entry already exists for that phone number in **distilled_contacts**, it should just be updated with the changes, if any. I am able to retrieve the name with the highest frequency using this query:

```
select NAME from `raw_contacts` RC1 where PHONE="11111" 
and FREQUENCY>=all (select FREQUENCY from `raw_contacts` RC2 where RC2.PHONE=RC1.PHONE) LIMIT 1
```

Now how do I write a trigger to **insert/update** this name and phone number into **distilled_contacts**? Here's my attempt:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
AFTER UPDATE
   ON `raw_contacts` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `distilled_contacts`
(PHONE, POPULARNAME)
select PHONE, NAME from `raw_contacts` RC1 where PHONE="11111" 
and FREQUENCY>=all (select FREQUENCY from `raw_contacts` RC2 where RC2.PHONE=RC1.PHONE) LIMIT 1 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE POPULARNAME = NAME
END;
```

But I am still unable to get my head around how to use a variable instead of "11111" to refer to the phone number in context, i.e. the value being inserted under the **PHONE** column of **raw_contacts**.

Comment: There's plenty of info out there on writing triggers. have a go and come back with some specific attempts and errors if you have any difficulties

Comment: Please see the revision in the question. I've been able to write the trigger but I don't know how to use the results of a query on one table to update another using this trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, got this to work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
AFTER UPDATE
   ON `raw_contacts` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `distilled_contacts`
(PHONE, POPULARNAME)
select PHONE, NAME from `raw_contacts` RC1 where PHONE=NEW.PHONE 
and FREQUENCY>=all (select FREQUENCY from `raw_contacts` RC2 where RC2.PHONE=RC1.PHONE) LIMIT 1 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE POPULARNAME = NAME
END;
```

I won't yet, however, mark this as accepted since I want to see if anyone out there has any suggestions to optimize the trigger (or the underlying query) further. This trigger will be fired after every insert/update and there will be potentially thousands of such events simultaneously. So any suggestion to make this more performance-friendly is greatly appreciated!